# Alignment of \input images in tabular

Tags: tables, input, readarray

I'm trying to create a tabular environment using two images: one is \input from gnuplot, while the other is \input from a \typesetarray from the array package.  My goal is to have them both aligned to the top of the page.  The array (on the right) keeps getting aligned at the bottom, which makes the rest of the page look crazy.

Can you please tell me how to get the two images to be top-aligned?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{readarray} 
\readarraysepchar{,}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\readdef{../psa-data.csv}\data
\readarray\data\array[\nrows,\ncols]

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\scalebox{0.9}{\input{../psaplot}} & \scalebox{0.8}{\input{../array}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you haven't shown any code but probably you are aligning the base of the image with the centre of the table. you could use a top aligned table and top align the image using `\raisebox` or more simply `adjustbox` package

Comment: Try using `tblr` package, it has functionalities to align various items in different ways.

Comment: Why not use the two column option of `paracol` instead of trying to get this done in a table environment? Paracol creates two parallel columns in which content is positioned at the top of each column, which seems to be the layout you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your clever answers.  @DavidCarlisle, I used your approach and it is perfect.  I was also able to learn about the adjustbox package, which will surely be helpful in the future.  Thanks again to all.

Comment: Instead of `\input`, why not put each into a `standalone` and use `\includegraphics`?  That will show any issues you have with unwanted white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, I used the \adjustbox package to \valign the two images.  This was perfect.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\scalebox{1}{\adjustbox{valign=T}{\input{psaplot}}} & \scalebox{0.95}{\adjustbox{valign=T}{\input{array}}}
\end{tabular}
```